# Defining Structures in Scheme. Hope for assistance

Tags: scheme, structure, racket

I'm fairly new to Scheme and I'm using DrRacket and I hope to get some much needed assistance.

I am defining structures, which I understand to an extent, but I have seem to have ran into a snag.

I need to make it so the "EmployeeRaise" function works for all the check-expects, without making it so it can only work for one specific check-expect.

The main problem is that in the definition, more specifically in the bolded part,

(+ (**employee-Hourly-rate em**) (* (**employee-Hourly-rate em**) 0.1)))

I can't seem to figure out how it can determine the employee's hourly rate for everyone and just not the employee that is defined with "em."

I would think having all three employees be defined with "em" but it won't let me do that.

I hope someone can assist me.

Here is my code:

```
(define-struct employee (Name Hourly-rate overtime?))

;;Signature: EmployeeRaise: string -> number
;;Purpose: Consumes an employee and returns an employee with the hourly rate increased by 10%.
;;Tests
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise "Ben") 13.2)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise "Joe") 16.5)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise "Debbie") 22)
;; Define
(define (EmployeeRaise employee-Name)
  (+ (employee-Hourly-rate em) (* (employee-Hourly-rate em) 0.1)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First your `EmployeeRaise` function should do what you describe in the "Signature" and take an `employee` structure (as returned by `make-employee`), not a `string`. So let's change the name of the argument to `em` to reflect that:

```
;;Signature: EmployeeRaise: employee -> number
;;Purpose: Consumes an employee and returns an employee with the hourly rate increased by 10%.
;;Tests
(define (EmployeeRaise em)
  (+ (employee-Hourly-rate em) (* (employee-Hourly-rate em) 0.1)))
```

Notice that this function is now operating on `em` the argument it's getting -- *not* the `em` "global variable" that you had before.

Next, for testing you could either do this:

```
(define ben (make-employee "Ben" 12 true))
(define joe (make-employee "Joe" 15 false))
(define deb (make-employee "Debbie" 20 true))

(check-expect (EmployeeRaise ben) 13.2)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise joe) 16.5)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise deb) 22)
```

Or simply this:

```
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise (make-employee "Ben" 12 true)) 13.2)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise (make-employee "Joe" 15 false)) 16.5)
(check-expect (EmployeeRaise (make-employee "Debbie" 20 true)) 22)
```

---

Note: I'm guessing you're using an htdp language? Since I don't know much about them, I couldn't guess which one, and I wasn't able to run the code above to ensure it's 100% correct. But I think what I'm describing should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It didn't work at first, but it worked after you edited it just now. Thank you!